# Can't access MySQL Database After deploying to the Cloud - CommunicationsException

Tags: java, mysql, rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I connect to my Google Cloud SQL via my App Engine Java Rest API Project to retrieve and store data on my cloud. I can successfully communicate with the server via Localhost but after I publish, I get this error:

> **Trying to Run Query:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure**
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

While there's so many solutions out there, I'm sad to say none of them worked.

**Here's my connection string:**

```
String url = null;
try {
    if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
        url = "jdbc:google:mysql://APP_ENGINE_ID:SQL_INSTANCE_NAME/DB_NAME?user=root";
    } else {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        url = "jdbc:mysql://MY_IPV4_ADDRESS:3306/DB_NAME?user=root";
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get this error via my Rest API after I publish it only. Basically, works via Localhost but not remotely on the cloud.

**I debugged and pin pointed the place where it crashes. It happens after I try to establish a connection with the server and execute a query:**

```
try {
    //THIS is where it crashes
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM UserTable";
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next())
        {
            //Code
        }
        st.close();
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Can you connect using MySQL client from the same machine? That should tell you if it's a connectivity issue or not. Once you have that working, then you can debug your app further.

Comment: I can connect to the database using MySQL Workbench so I guess it's not a connection issue? I just can't seem to connect after I deploy it @jarmod

Comment: did you put `use-google-connector-j` option into `appengine-web.xml`?

Comment: You mean <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j> ? Yes I added that as well. Still no luck @IgorArtamonov

Comment: Is it standard appengine vm, or flexible vm?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't fully understood that? Do you mean my Google App Engine Type? @IgorArtamonov

Comment: yes, app engine type. Standard Environment or Flexible?

Comment: If by Flexible you mean 'Bill per usage', yes that's the one I have @IgorArtamonov

Comment: I mean this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ or this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I have the Standard Environment mate

Comment: ok. and 1st get Cloud SQL, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean mate :D 1st get? Yes the error comes when I execute the query @IgorArtamonov

Comment: there're two types of CloudSQL, it asks you when you create a new db which of them you want to use. "Second Generation" and "First Generation"

Comment: Mine is First Generation Igor @IgorArtamonov

Comment: Then it should work with current config. Are you sure you're using correct substitutions for `APP_ENGINE_ID:SQL_INSTANCE_NAME/DB_NAME`?

Comment: Yes cos it works properly on Localhost Igor. When I publish this weird error pops up. Can you check my connection string please? Is it correct? @IgorArtamonov

Comment: Also, do I have to add 0.0.0.0 to the Allowed IP Addresses in my Google SQL Settings? @IgorArtamonov

Comment: on localhost you're using `jdbc:mysql://MY_IPV4_ADDRESS:3306/DB_NAME?user=root`. I'm talking about production `jdbc:google:mysql://APP_ENGINE_ID:SQL_INSTANCE_NAME/DB_NAME?user=root`.
you shouldn't add 0.0.0.0

Comment: Dang man everything looks okay to me. So confused. Thanks Igor :( @IgorArtamonov

Comment: Is the Cloud SQL instance in the same project as the App Engine application?

Comment: Also the first part should be the project ID, not APP_ENGINE_ID (but it could be the same depending on what you are putting there)

Comment: When you look at your cloud sql instance in https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances, is your app engine application ID under Access control -> App Engine Application ID ?

Comment: @Herman Yes thank you, there was a problem with my Project_ID:INSTANCE_ID. Fixed it :)

Comment: @Vadim Yes thank you, there was a problem with my Project_ID:INSTANCE_ID. Fixed it :)

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Yes thank you, there was a problem with my Project_ID:INSTANCE_ID. Fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Herman, Igor and Vadim pointed out, it was a simply error in my PROJECT_ID:INSTANCE_ID in this line:

**Incorrect Code:**

```
if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
    url = "jdbc:google:mysql://APP_ENGINE_ID:SQL_INSTANCE_NAME/DB_NAME?user=root";
}
```

I've been using my **App engine ID** instead of the **Project ID**, which I should have been using.

**Corrected Code:**

```
if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
    url = "jdbc:google:mysql://PROJECT_ID:SQL_INSTANCE_NAME/DB_NAME?user=root";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

as You can see i have called using asyncTask in Android (same as Thread in java )

```
public class Connect extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> 
 {
  protected Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

    Connection connection;
    String query = "Some query";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<your cloud IP address>/<database schema you want to connect to>", "<user>", "<password>");

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

hope you got it now :)

Comment: So the Querying part should be in the same thread as well? Or is it just the connection part?

Comment: whole task of getting connection and Querying comes in thread